# How to generate random numbers with an "increment" between them, for a Teeter html5 game

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am developing a teeter game and I need some help.

Right now, I am randomly generating the coordinates of 10 points on the HTML5 canvas.

Lets say the canvas is 500 px by 500 px - I have made the points generate between 100 and 400, thus concentrating their positions away from the canvas borders.

For this, I am using the function **randomFromInterval()** - **xw** and **xh** representing the height and width of the canvas.

From those 10 points (each with their x and y coordinates on the canvas):
- 5 points will be the center of **crosses**
- 5 points will be the center of **Holes**

When the ball (which the user navigated) gets over a cross, he will get points, if he falls into a hole he looses.

**Here is my problem:**

**Due to the randomness of the numbers - some coordinate get too close to the others - so I could have part of a "hole", drawn over the cross.**

Right now, some pair of random numbers could be: [1, 5] and [2, 6]

If I draw the **cross** at x = 1 and y = 5 (coordinates on the canvas) and I draw the **hole** at x = 2 and y = 6, those two would overlap.

Here is the code:

```
function randomFromInterval(from,to){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(to-from+1)+from);
}

function crossesAndHoles(){
        var crossx, crossy, col;
        for(var i=0; i<=10; i++){
            crossPos = [];
            crossx = randomFromInterval(100, xw-100); // the xw  is the width of the canvas
            crossy = randomFromInterval(100, xh-100); // the xh is the height of the canvas
            col = checkcollision(crossx, crossy, xdim); // here I check the collision with the maze which is drew on the canvas
            if((crossx != crossy) && col == 0){
                crossPos.push(crossx);
                crossPos.push(crossy);
                crossesPos.push(crossPos);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: ... Compare the values and ensure they're at least 4 apart?

Comment: You know, sometimes asking something means you have to go through it properly... I was just thinking the same thing - I could store each pair of values into an array and than generate values that are bigger with a certain value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each new coordinate generated you could check its distance against the previously generated coordinates... if it's too close, then generate a new one.